# Leaving a page - message appears twice

Tags: javascript

I've added this Javascript to my website which detects when the user navigates away from the page, but I only want a warning to appear if the navigator is offline AND one of my  elements contains the word "unsaved":

```
window.thisPage = window.thisPage || {};
window.thisPage.closeEditorWarning = function (event) {
 if (navigator.onLine===false) {
  // See if any fields need saving...
  for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++) { 
   try {
    ToSave = document.getElementById("Q" + i).innerHTML;
    if (ToSave.indexOf("unsaved")!=-1) {
     return "You are currently offline and some of your responses are not yet saved.\r\n\r\nIf you want to save the changes you've made, choose to 'Stay on this Page' and then reconnect to the internet and any unsaved responses will save automatically.";
    }
   }
   catch(err) {  }
   // If got this far, nothing needs saving anyway...
  }
 }
 return undefined;
};

window.onbeforeunload = window.thisPage.closeEditorWarning;
```

The code works fine except; if the message pops up the **first time** and I choose "Stay on this page", then try to navigate away again and the **second time** click "Leave this page" - rather than navigating away it displays the message again but I can't work out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `true` from your catch, so the unload will execute. You can also remove the `return undefined;` from the end.

This works for me, is this what you're after?

This works for me in Firefox.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/518myq0j/3/ (clicking 'Run' triggers the `onbeforeunload`)

Updated JavaScript code:

```
window.thisPage = window.thisPage || {};

window.thisPage.closeEditorWarning = function (event) {
    if (navigator.onLine === false) {
        // See if any fields need saving...
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            try {
                var ToSave = document.getElementById("Q" + i).innerHTML;
                if (ToSave.indexOf("unsaved") != -1) {
                    return "You are currently offline and some of your responses are not yet saved.\r\n\r\nIf you want to save the changes you've made, choose to 'Stay on this Page' and then reconnect to the internet and any unsaved responses will save automatically.";
                }
            } catch (err) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
};

window.onbeforeunload = window.thisPage.closeEditorWarning;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still appears twice if I choose "Stay on this page" the first time and "Leave this page" the second time. Using Internet Explorer, will try in Firefox.

Comment: Ideally I wanted the question to only appear if the browser is offline, your code triggers whether the browser is offline or online. It works fine if the browser is online but if you go offline the message appears twice.

Comment: Hey, this works for me in Firefox 38.0.5 (I updated the answer to remove the `(true || false)` I added for testing purposes)